# 2DCollider detection error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working with 2D Unity game and I have object named 'make' and another object named 'tree'.

I'm trying to detect if 'make' collides with 'tree' and this is what I've tried so far:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("Collided");
}
```

And I have tried the non-2D version of that too, event still doesn't fire.

```
if (transform.renderer.bounds.Intersects(GameObject.Find("tree").transform.renderer.bounds)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collided");
    }
```

I included this in the Update() method of Movement script that only 'make' has. And yet again, no success.

Is there a solution that doesn't involve Gravity (RigidBody, etc.), but rather a BoxCollider2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your colliders have IsTrigger checked, and make sure at least one has a RigidBody2D attached to it. Uncheck Use Gravity on your RigidBody if you don't want gravity.

Answer (score 1):

This graph tells you what collides with what in Unity3D.

[image]

In your case the code should be like this example:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Collided");
    }
}
```